# How Update structural changes in the customer sql server database

Tags: sql-server, database

We will deliver a program to the client, after a while, we will prepare a new version of the program. We also make changes to the sql database (for example, added a new table, or added fields to existing ones, we've added a relationship).

My question is how to create a script from a new database that is delivered to the client and implemented by the client and made high changes in its database. And there is no problem for customer data.

Comment: Are you saying that the client may have made changes to the database schema?

Comment: Unclear, please provide an example.

Comment: Too broad as there are many ways/tools to accomplish this. There are tools that can diff two SQL Servers and update the target from the source. You can write custom scripts as well to do your table/column/etc adds and data updates.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a DACPAC, with the option "don't go ahead if we might lose data".

Comment: Have you tried using SSMS to modify a table, but before hitting save, look at the script that it would generate. It is a lot of SQL, but is a great example of the way to do what you are asking.